# How should I configure my Audio settings for the highest quality sound?

Tags: audio, macbook-pro

I would like to configure my Mac and Thunderbolt display for the best Audio output.  The "Audio Devices" tab allows me to choose

- Audio Format in Hz
- 2 channel xx bit Integer or Float

What configuration offers the best sound?  I suppose higher in Hz is better, and more bits are better, but I don't know if I should choose 24bit integer or 32bit float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

48000Hz is more than adequate for the audio range as there are not going to be any pre-recorded formats above this, and the human ear can only hear around 20000Hz anyway. CDs are only 44100, most DVDs now are at 48000, and while BluRay supports 96000 it's unlikely the audio is actually recorded in that quality.

24bit integer vs 32bit float is actually the same quality, the 8 floating bits on the later are for other things which generally come into play with music production I believe.

Comment: The [Boom](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/boom/id415312377?mt=12) equalizer and volume booster uses 32-bit *integer*.